# Read/Write permission on USB drive mounted on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, permissions, usb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm running a rooted Android-6 Marshmallow media box.

To it I have a external USB drive attached, formatted as NTFS (I believe it's NTFS. It's been a long while since I set this up).

The drive is mounted as:

```
/mnt/media_rw/<15-digit-hex-number>
```

The permissions are currently **rwxrwx---** (0x770)

I don't know what changed, but I used to be able to **WRITE** to that USB drive. No longer. Only **READ** is possible now. Similarly, the Android file manager app **Root Explorer** use to be able to freely change permissions on that top-level directory (to change it to **0x777**) as well as to files and directories beneath it. Again, no longer.

As prescribed elsewhere, I incorporated the appropriated addition to the following system file:

```
/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml

[ ... snip ... ]
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_r" />
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
    <group gid="media_rw" />
</permission>

<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
    <group gid="media_rw" />
</permission>
[ ... snip ... ]
```

I'm getting permission denied when I try to either WRITE access that directory (meaning enter into the USB drive); as well as when I use **Root Explorer** to relax permissions on that directory to gain access (also permission denied).

I didn't upgrade Android or anything like that. It just stopped working.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not long after I posted this lengthy question did I, by chance, figure out the issue. That mount point has to be accessed via an alternate path/route:

```
/storage/<15-digit-hex-number>
```

I believe what happened is that, whereas the particular application accessing that folder could previously do so via the original path specified (in the Question), that path/route is, perhaps, somehow restrictive/special and that application suddenly started respecting that restriction (and therefore could no longer write via that original path). I just found this out by looking at a different application that writes to the same place, and noticed the alternate path/route it was using (i.e. the one above).

If you should run into this issue, try starting the path traversal at **/storage/** instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue, and realized even root user had issues writing (or even getting information) from USB storage.

Unfortunately I have no /storage/<15-digits> folder visible, with or without root.

My app actually fall-backs to SAF, which allows read/write to external storage (actual SD cards) and it works on USB storage was well. However it's slow like hell and path are definitely not user friendly!

Digging deeper into this, root was able to do file listing of any folders, but couldn't get information about specific files or folders using direct path !?

Hence my solution (already implemented for external storage) was to treat USB storage like an external storage and fallback to SAF whenever necessary (mostly writing data to USB storage). AND I tweaked root to use file listing with all data shown (a customized version of ls -l) instead of trying to get direct information for files/directories.

The 'easiest' to get full access to USB storage is thus through SAF file-system. Root can be, but used using various tricks!

Tested on Pixel 3 running Android Pie with february 2019 patch.

FWIWI, since Android N, the platform.xml no longer defines these permissions, which are now stored in packages.xml.